# s3.listObjectsV2 is not a function NodeJs

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

I've following lambda function for fetching list of all the keys from S3, however, it ends up in error message as `s3.listObjectsV2 is not a function`. Not sure what's wrong. The code is taken from another SO post, however it doesn't seem to be working.

Code:

```
    const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    var request=true;
    const awsOptions = {
        region: "us-east-1"
    };
    const s3 = new AWS.S3(awsOptions);
    
    exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
        
        const SrcBucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
        const trigger_file = event.Records[0].s3.object.key;
            
        var bucketParams = {
            Bucket: SrcBucket,
            Prefix: 'Temp/',
        };
    
        var allKeys = [];
    
        listAllKeys();
        function listAllKeys()
        {
          s3.listObjectsV2(bucketParams, function (err, data) 
          {
            if (err) 
            {
              console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
            } 
            else 
            {
              var contents = data.Contents;
              contents.forEach(function (content) {
               allKeys.push(content.Key);
               });
    
            if (data.IsTruncated) {
             bucketParams.ContinuationToken = data.NextContinuationToken;
             console.log("get further list...");
             listAllKeys();
             }
          }
          });
        }
 console.log(allKeys.length);
}
```

Comment: are you testing this locally or from AWS console? if you are testing from aws console, aws-sdk already pre-installed, we shouldn't get this error.

Comment: @BaluVyamajala I'm testing from VS, yeah basically locally.

Comment: yaa.. we will need to setup a basic npm project with aws-sdk dependency

Comment: @BaluVyamajala I've the same result from AWS console too `"errorMessage": "s3.listObjectsV2 is not a function",
`